# A Different Kind of Treasure Hunt

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, treasure-hunt

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #27: Treasure-Hunt](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/fortnightly-topic-challenge-27-treasure-hunt)...</sup>

---

*There is more treasure in books than in all the pirate's loot on Treasure Island.*
                                            <sup>— Walt Disney</sup>

Put on your hiking boots, we're going on a treasure hunt—for **words**!

You'll be exploring the free encyclopedia that anyone can edit, looking for 13 words which will, perhaps, sum up both your experience with solving this puzzle and my experience with setting it.  To get you started, I've already given you 3½ of the words.  You'll have to find the rest....
And to find those, you'll have to figure out HOW to find the rest.

Good luck!

### The clues:

> 1. A tubular section or hollow cylinder used mainly to convey substances which flow.
> 2. A collection of tissues joined in a structural unit to serve a common function.
> 3. Money given to an organization, especially one that helps people.
> 4. NHL penalty area?
> 5. An passage underground.
> 6. You must go to it, if it does not come to you.
> 7. Felis catus is your taxonomic nomenclature, An endothermic quadruped, carnivorous by nature.
> 8. As of 2008, more than one in two humans live in one.
> 9. He often looks good in a suit?
> 10. Like this clue: not very specific.
> 11. People in general.
> 12. Congress has an important one?
> 13. A pile of hay.
> 14. A knight for a knight.

### The hidden treasure:

1 ——
    |—————————  **P1W5**
2 ——
    |—————————  **P1W6**
3 ——
    |—————————  ***who***
4  ——
    |—————————  **P9W38**
5  ——
    |—————————  **P6W28**
6  ——
    |—————————  ***made***
7  ——
    |—————————  **P1W8**
8  ——
    |—————————  ***mistake***
9  ——
    |—————————  **P6W116**
10 -—
    |—————————  **1985: P1W1**
11 -—
    |—————————  **P5W21**
12 -—
    |—————————  **P2W102 + *thing***
13 -—
    |—————————  **P4W9**
14 -—

*____*
<sub>*Because the nature of this particular hunt means that over time some, if not all, the treasure may be taken away by others, once solved I will replace the current treasure clues with ones that do not require an off-site resource.*</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thirteen words are

> [A person who has never made a mistake has never tried anything new](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/alberteins148788.html)

The clues: (thanks to @MOehm for getting 8, 9 and 10)

> 1. [Pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_(fluid_conveyance))
>  2. [Organ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organ_(anatomy))
>  3. Donation
>  4. [Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_box)
>  5. [Tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel)
>  6. [Mountain](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_the_mountain_won't_come_to_Muhammad)
>  7. [Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_(Star_Trek)#Spot) (the clue is from [Ode to Spot](http://www.sjtrek.com/trek/ode/)
>  8. City
>  9. Attorney
>  10. General
>  11. Public
>  12. [Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_of_Congress)
>  13. Stack (i.e. haystack)
>  14. Exchange

Now, note that

> we can combine consecutive words into a valid page on Wikipedia.

If we then

> take the word from that page using the paragraph and word numbers given, we get:
>  [Pipe organ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_organ): a
>  [Organ donation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organ_donation): person
>  [Donation box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donation_box): *who*
>  [Box tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_Tunnel): has
>  [Tunnel Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_Mountain): never
>  [Mountain cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_cat): *made*
>  [Cat City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_City): a
>  [City attorney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_attorney): *mistake*
>  [Attorney general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attorney_general): has
>  [General Public](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Public): never
>  [Public library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_library): tried
>  [Library stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_stack): any+thing
>  [Stack Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange): new

These words form the quote given above.

Comment: Nice. That was too quick :) +1

Comment: My favorite thing about this puzzle is that knowing the answer doesn't help *at all* in solving the clues :)  Looking good so far ...

Comment: Very good! I think 8 is City and 10 is General, which gives [Cat City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_City) and [General Public](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Public). The words on these pages fit your answer.

Comment: The one who may look good in a (law) suit is an Attorney: [City attorney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_attorney) and [Attorney general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attorney_general). And the 116th word in paragraph 6 is indeed "has". (Yes, I did count up to 116, Your Honour.)

Comment: Nicely done :)  Hope that was fun - well, other than counting to 116 anyway hehe

Answer (score 1):

Partial

> Some of these are the lines from the Wikipedia about particular things and a few look like crossword clues.

1. A tubular section or hollow cylinder used mainly to convey substances which flow.

> [PIPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_%28fluid_conveyance%29)

2. A collection of tissues joined in a structural unit to serve a common function

> [ORGAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organ_%28anatomy%29)

3. Money given to an organization, especially one that helps people.

> Probably **CHARITY**

4. NHL penalty area?

> [PENALTY BOX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_box)

5. An passage underground.

> [TUNNEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel)

6. You must go to it, if it does not come to you.

> Probably a [PROVERBIAL PHRASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_proverbial_phrases) or **MOUNTAIN**

7. Felis catus is your taxonomic nomenclature, An endothermic quadruped, carnivorous by nature.

> [ODE TO SPOT](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Ode_to_Spot)

8. As of 2008, more than one in two humans live in one.

> Might be [HUMAN-ANIMAL HYBRID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human%E2%80%93animal_hybrid) as it refers to more than 1 in 2. So, could be one and a half.

9. He often looks good in a suit?

> Not sure yet

10. Like this clue: not very specific.

> Probably **VAGUE**

11. People in general.

> Probably **THEY**

12. Congress has an important one?

> [POWERS?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powers_of_the_United_States_Congress)

13. A pile of hay.

> Probably **RICK**

14. A knight for a knight.

> Not sure. May be [Sir KAY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_Kay)

Next step

> is to figure out how many of them are correct and how do they fit in those blanks.

Comment: 6 is likely mountain